# Why is YSlow suggesting gziping image files?

Tags: html, http, gzip, yslow, web-optimization

Yslow is suggesting me to compress the image files which is kind of pointless in my opinion.

Is it, though? Should I really listen to YSlow here?

**Edit:**

Here are the response headers:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>
> x-amz-id-2:
>   FYOpJwFZR03v32xpx8eSjKCuy4Wb/vRcFznQf90ZpYStS4iAOU9JErGvymwGMRXK
>
> x-amz-request-id: B3D887ED3BC713C8
>
> Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 14:26:16 GMT
>
> Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 14:06:58 GMT
>
> ETag: "2b04df3ecc1d94afddff082d139c6f15"
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Content-Length: 780831
>
> Server: AmazonS3
>
> Age: 28933
>
> X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
>
> X-Amz-Cf-Id:
>   wVF39GJ806IW1rMxjxc1sBEApYy3JEE5lRrv9e8FI0NMrhlPtCWihQ==,jj0bZ4bK8kwN1uA7J4HBPMhmNOI37S2ltl5_oSeZyA_mDypL_UiCuQ==
>
> Via: 1.0 6ed32821244f98865b8d2952067f0d2a.cloudfront.net:11180
>   (CloudFront), 1.0
>   d07b275858a148b34d17d395d65e6920.cloudfront.net:11180 (CloudFront)
>
> Connection: keep-alive

Comment: That sounds strange. What kind of an image? Which format? How large is it? What is YSlow exactly saying?

Comment: How are the images currently formatted/compressed/stored? JPEG, PNG, TIFF?

Comment: Iffy, very iffy. That woluld be well down on my list of things to try unless they were two colour wire graphic bitmaps or something, and if they were, I'd convert them to something vector based....

Comment: YSlow should not be suggesting compression (i.e. gzip) of images. Perhaps it was suggesting "optimization" (i.e. lossless compression)? If you can post a web URL for a page in which you're seeing this, we can take a closer look.

Comment: @BrianC no, it is suggesting to gzip the file not optimize it.

Comment: Can you post a sample web page link?

Comment: @BrianC this AWS S3 account is not my personal account. It is a corporate one.

Answer (score 0):

gzipping JPEG would give you no improvement - JPEG is already very efficient (yet lossy) at compressing said image, and the return on compressing them with gzip is negligible.

On the other hand, PNG/TIFF/GIF files are usually already gzipped to begin with, and so you will get a larger object if you re-compress it.

In short, no good will come of re-compressing a compressed format, so don't bother.